# Make downvoted answers more easily readable?

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

When reading some of the random questions on the site, you sometimes see a downvoted answer. You typically see a response of why that is a bad answer. I often see the value of reading them finding out why that is a bad idea or why it is not something that you should be doing.

Now the problem I have is that often with them being greyed out I find them very difficult to read (grey on a white background). I understand that we don't want a user to find the question on a search engine and assume its a good answer. Is there any consideration in adding a account setting that would allow it to display as a normal answer for those who are logged in and want to read those answers without straining our eyes.

Comment: I disagree.  If an answer is *that* downvoted, perhaps it's a bad idea to read it.

Comment: @Makoto You should at least be able to read the comments and find out why it is a bad answer.

Comment: You can use a userscript to change how the CSS is rendered if you want.  It's readability does depend on your monitor, it's settings, and your OS settings too.  I know it's much harder for me to read on one of my monitors over another.

Comment: @Makoto The way I look it is maybe the bad answer is one of the ways I thought of approaching a problem. I want to see the community's logic of why it is a bad answer.

Comment: A downvoted answer may always be useful, it may happen that some users downvote it for their own mistake, even if rarely.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri 3 times by mistake? That is indeed rarely ;)

Comment: It may happen that at first gets downvoted and reaches 2-3 downvotes, then after some hours it starts getting upvotes because they understand that it was correct.

Comment: In which case the answer would be normally visible again

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much support, so you could just use a userscript, as Servy has pointed out. `$('.downvoted-answer').removeClass('.downvoted-answer')` should do it.